# Python ignore character and print next character from list in for loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am using BeautifulSoup4 and requests to scrape information from a website.

I then store the required information in lists, there are two lists for two different types of information I scraped from the page.

```
    try:
        for i in range(0,1000):
            location = dive_data1[((9*i)-7)].text
            locations.append(location)
            location = dive_data2[((9*i)-7)]
            locations.append(location)
            depth = dive_data1[((9*i)-6)].text
            depths.append(depth)
            depth = dive_data2[((9*i)-6)].text
            depths.append(depth)

    except:
        pass
```

After that I try to pass these lists into another for loop to write the contents into a CSV file.

```
    try:
        writer = csv.writer(dive_log)
        writer.writerow( ("Locations and depths") )
        writer.writerow( ("Sourced from:", str(url_page)) )
        writer.writerow( ("Location", "Depth") )
        for i in range(len(locations)):
            writer.writerow( (locations[i], depths[i]) )
```

when i run the script i recieve this error:

```
writer.writerow( (locations[i], depths[i]) )
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 65-66:      ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried this to pass characters it cannot encode:

```
    writer = csv.writer(dive_log)
    writer.writerow( ("Locations and depths") )
    writer.writerow( ("Sourced from:", str(url_page)) )
    writer.writerow( ("Location", "Depth") )
    for i in range(len(locations)):
        try:
            writer.writerow( (locations[i], depths[i]) )

        except:
            pass
```

When I run this, only the lines prior to the for loop are excecuted and it completely passes the repeat of the for loop.

The entirety of the code in my script is copied below in case it is related to something that I had not seen in the rest.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

dive_log = open("divelog.csv", "wt")
url_page = "https://en.divelogs.de/log/Mark_Gosling"
r = requests.get(url_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

dive_data1 = soup.find_all("tr", {"class": "td2"})
dive_data2 = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "td"})
locations = []
depths = []

try:
    for i in range(0,1000):
        location = dive_data1[((9*i)-7)].text
        locations.append(location)
        location = dive_data2[((9*i)-7)]
        locations.append(location)
        depth = dive_data1[((9*i)-6)].text
        depths.append(depth)
        depth = dive_data2[((9*i)-6)].text
        depths.append(depth)

except:
    pass

try:
    writer = csv.writer(dive_log)
    writer.writerow( ("Locations and depths") )
    writer.writerow( ("Sourced from:", str(url_page)) )
    writer.writerow( ("Location", "Depth") )
    for i in range(len(locations)):
        try:
            writer.writerow( (locations[i], depths[i]) )

        except:
            pass

finally:
    dive_log.close()

print open("divelog.csv", "rt").read()
print "\n\n"
print locations
```

Comment: this should do the trick with characters it cant encode: `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))`

Comment: Don't ignore anything unless you are ok losing data, figure out the correct encoding to use then use that.  The data is also utf-8 encoded so the problem lies elsewhere. Also don't use blanket excepts, catch what you expect and log/print the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode to *utf-8* in the loop when you write:

```
for i in range(len(locations)):
        writer.writerow((locations[i].encode("utf-8"), depths[i].encode("utf-8")) )
```

Answer (score -1):

Like @yedpodtriztko noted. You can just leave the characters that it cannot decode with following:

instead of doing:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

you could use this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```